# How can I access text box elements in a specific third-party application window?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, cocoa, accessibility

My requirement is to launch a third-party application from my application and auto-fill the username into a specified text box. Currently, I am able to launch the application and have tried using the Cocoa framework but I can only get the window information, not the elements inside. I’ve also attempted using the Accessibility API, and when I analyzed with Accessibility Inspector, I found that the parent role of the element I needed was Window, but this element didn’t appear in the Window’s children. I don’t know how to proceed. Is there any other method that could help me accomplish this?

I’ve tried using the Cocoa framework but can only obtain the information of the window, without knowing how to grab the elements inside. I’ve also attempted to use the Accessibility API to retrieve them.

Comment: Is this mystery text box a regular Cocoa control, or rendered from something like a HTML document?

Comment: Can you navigate to the text box using the arrow/tab keys? Can the Accessibility Inspector select the text box?

Comment: The type of the text box is Text Field, and the Element Class is NSTextFieldCell. I can inspect it with the Accessibility Inspector. However, when I check its Parent, I find that the Parent’s Children do not include it, and the Parent only contains an AXGroup.

Comment: Unfortunately macOS Accessibility can be inconsistent, and have broken hierarchies, as you see. What I have been doing in some cases is get the deepest reliable element, and then make a mouse click relative to it's AXFrame to get to the Button/TextField I want. Depends on individual conditions.

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas provided. Now the way I’m using is through AXUIElementCopyElementAtPosition to get it. First, I get the coordinates of the main window, and then calculate the coordinates of the control I want to get. I have been able to get it. Thank you very much for your help. You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `CGEvent` and send event like the new mouse position and keystrokes for instance:

#### Move the mouse programmatically:

```
private func moveMouseTo(x: Int, y: Int) {
    let moveEvent = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .mouseMoved, mouseCursorPosition: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), mouseButton: .left)
    moveEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}
```

#### Send keystrokes programmatically:

```
let keyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: rightArrowKeyCode, keyDown: true)
keyDownEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
keyDownEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)

let keyUpEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: rightArrowKeyCode, keyDown: false)
keyUpEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
keyUpEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
```

Note that in order to use both events (mouse and keyboard) you need to configure the "Accessibility" option in macOS Settings for your app, like **[AXIsProcessTrusted](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1460720-axisprocesstrusted?language=objc)**

---

You can use also, OCR or a machine learning model using CreateML (for image recognition) to identify the correct bounding box of your 3rd party app (in particular to your textfield).

In this way you can move the mouse and click in a precise position than send keystrokes.